# How to pass class method as parameter?

Tags: ruby

I want to pass a class method to another function, how can I do that?

```
class A
  def A.test(data)
    puts data
  end
end

def ps(fun)
  fun(3)
end

ps(A.test)
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? That way you might receive more useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the right getter to receive the method object:

```
class A
 def A.test(data)
    puts data
  end
end

def ps(fun)
  fun.call(3)
end

ps(A.method(:test)) #=> 3
```

The [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Object.html#method-i-method) method returns the method-object, which can be executed with [`call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-call).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass just the `method_name` to `ps` and have `ps` send the `method_name` message to the `A` class (and always the `A` class) using this:

```
class A
    def A.test(data)
        puts data
    end
end

def ps(method_name)
    A.send(method_name, 3)
end

ps(:test) # => 3
```

Or you can pass both the `A` class and the `method_name` to `ps` using this:

```
class A
    def A.test(data)
        puts data
    end
end

def ps(klass, method_name)
    klass.send(method_name, 3)
end

ps(A, :test) # => 3
```